# How to search for a question mark in Twitter

Tags: twitter, search

I have been searching for an hour trying to figure out how to use the question mark in a search, basically I'm looking for the string ?tag (as in the Amazon Affiliates Tag Link) I'm basically trying to find all tweets that have an amazon affiliate link in them.

Also can you use *'s or other things in the searches? I.E. am*?tag or something (starting with the amazon link and then having a ?tag in the link), I tried /? but that doesn't appear to have made a difference.

Answer (score 1):

So for me, just seaching for a question mark, finds tweets with a question mark...

[image]

But what I find interesting is that searching for 'really?' doesn't find "really?" it finds 'really' and '?' in any order...

[image]

(And that's even if quoted).

There's also a problem in that you are looking for particular links, in a ecosystem where many of the links are shortened, which is going to be a problem unless you spider ever link going past on twitter - and I don't see an effective way of doing that... :(

Comment: Interesting, hadn't come across that. I wonder if that is expected behavior by Twitter.